# Integration test cron job is not running

Tags: magento2, database, cron, testing, integration-test

I want to test code with `integration test` that uses cron. The code, what runs by `integration test`, creates entry to cron_schedule table, but cron does not run created cron-job when it is designated. Why?

- How can I run cron-job that is located in integration database programmatically?
- Does correctly configured cron also can run cron-job in `integration test` database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a case of the [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should not *need* to run a cronjob from the schedule table in the integration test  database. Instead write one test, that only tests *if* the cronjob is configured correctly, and another one that tests execution of the cronjob by calling the execute method directly from the test.

If you want to know more, please show your test code and explain what you are trying to achieve with the test.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling the execute method directly from the test" the execute method is in xml file? I mean by that, how can I make sure that crontab.xml is correctly composed? Should I test it altogether?

Comment: @user3748173 I mean, call `$cron->execute()` (where `$cron` is your custom cron model) if you want to test what happens when the cron is executed. And if you want, create another test that checks if `crontab.xml` is working. It seems like you already got this covered in the current test: assert that an entry in `cron_schedule` exists and be done with it. But you can replace that test with a simpler one: instantiate `Magento\Cron\Model\Cron` and call `getJobs()`, then assert that the result contains your job.